# Enabling Web Inspector for the BlackBerry10 Browser from simulator

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-simulator, web-inspector, vmware-player

I am running **BB10 simulator** in **Windows7** PC using **VMware Player** with **bridge connection**. Web pages are opeming in BB10 Browser.

I want to enable **developer tool** to test my web application in **BB10 Browser**.

According tho the given link :

https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/getting_started_webinsp_microsite_1987477_11.html

I tried enabling Web Inspector but when i turned it on, it show the status :

**IP Address

Not Connected**

I have searched **google** a lot. Can anyone please suggest me any solution regarding above problem ?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? i am stuck on the same thing!

Comment: @deweydb Yes, if running BB10 inside the simulator then, type ip address showing in the bottom left corner of the simulator followed by port "1337" (i.e. 192.168.10.256:1337)in google chrome. No need to check ip address from browser's web inspector but make sure that web inspector in on from the browser.It was not working previously but after several attempt and using NAT in vmware adapter setting, it started working. [although i am not sure why it was not working previously].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run Web inspector from Google chrome your BB10 device must be connected form the system (either by USB or wifi). In case of BB10 simulator, as vmware adapter is already connected to your system adapter so you need not to worry about ip address showed by BB10 browser's Web Inspector option.

To start Web Ispector of BB10 browser from Google chrome follow the 3 steps:

1. Select NAT as vmware network adapter setting (It should also work with Bridge connection but i have only tried with NAT).
2. On the Web Inspector in from the BB10 Browser.
3. Type IP address showing in the bottom left corner of the simulator followed by default port "1337" (i.e. 192.168.10.256:1337)in Google Chrome.

It will start working.